# Merge multiple files and split output to multiple files based in each column (post 2)

Tags: awk

I have many csv files with exactly same format on rows and columns. In the example below I present only 2 files as input, but i have a lot files with same characteristics

The purpose is for each input file do:

Take value in row 1, 2 and 3.

example in first file

```
6174
15
3
```

Then, print first column from row 4 to 6.

Do same process for all input files and output a file with all information of all readed files.

When the process is done for all files and first column. Do the same of the rest columns

At the end the total files output created will be 4 files as there is 4 columns in each file.

**Input1**

```
Record Number 6174
Vibrator Identification 15
Start Time Error 3 us
1.6,19.5,,,
1.7,23.2,28.3,27.0
1.8,26.5,27.0,25.4
```

**Input2**

```
Record Number 6176
Vibrator Identification 17
Start Time Error 5 us
1.6,18.6,,,
1.5,23.5,19.7,19.2
1.3,26.8,19.2,18.5
```

Using the code below, I got the 4 output files as desired, although files 3-4, are not good as spected, because in the first lines there is empty values and my code does not work as supposed. Also I have an issue to get the good value in row 3 in each file.. I get us instead of a number.

**output file1**

```
6174,15,3,1.6,1.7,1.8
6176,17,5,1.6,1.5,1.3
```

**output file2**

```
6174,15,3,19.5,23.2,26.5
6176,17,5,18.6,23.5,26.8
```

**output file3**

```
6174,15,3,0,0,28.3,27.0
6176,17,5,0,0,19.7,19.2
```

**output file4**

```
6174,15,3,0,0,27.0,25.4
6176,17,5,0,0,19.2,18.5
```

**code used**

The code works almost fine, merge the csv files and output the 4 files requerides, but there is a problem for files 3-4, when there is empty values.

```
        for f in *.csv ; do

        awk -F, 'NR==1 {n=split($NF,f," ");print f[n]}' "$f" >> a-"$f"
        awk -F, 'NR==2 {n=split($NF,f," ");print f[n]}' "$f" >> a-"$f"
        awk -F, 'NR==3 {n=split($NF,f," ");print f[n]}' "$f" >> a-"$f"
        sed -i  's/\r$//' a-"$f"

        for i in seq $(1...4); do
        awk -F, 'NR>=4{f=1} f{print '"$""$i"'} f==6{exit}' "$f" > "a""$i"-"$f"

            cat a-"$f" a"$i""-""$f" >> t"$i" 

            sed -i  's/\r$//' t"$i" 

        done

                for i in seq $(1...4); do
                awk -v RS= -v OFS=',' -v ORS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' t"$i" > file"$i".csv

    done

done

rm -f ./a*  ./t*
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Interestingly, you didn't post the input files where you have a problem with your script.

Comment: @ Mr Ed, updated for input files and code done,, I use the shellcheck.net site to try to improve the code.

Comment: Hi karakfa, The issue in the input files is only when there is empty values like ",," .. then the code does not works fine, shoulbe at least ,0,0 in the input file...

Comment: @OXXO FYI if it's me you're trying to reach, I don't see messages tagged with any variation of `@Mr Ed`. You'd have to use the tag `@EdMorton` for me to see them.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot for the answer it works fine, but for some reason it outposts single file ? .. I am looking to the code to understand if I am doing something wrong...

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE and automatic handling of multiple open files and assuming your posted sample output showing file3 and file4 each having more fields than file1 and file2 is a mistake:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; numHdrFlds=3 }
FNR <= numHdrFlds {
    gsub(/[^0-9]/,"")
    hdr = (FNR==1 ? "" : hdr OFS) $0
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        data[i] = (FNR==(numHdrFlds+1) ? "" : data[i] OFS) ($i)+0
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<=NF; fileNr++ ) {
        print hdr, data[fileNr] > ("outputFile" fileNr)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2

$ for i in outputFile*; do echo "$i"; cat "$i"; echo "---"; done
outputFile1
6174,15,3,1.6,1.7,1.8
6176,17,5,1.6,1.5,1.3
---
outputFile2
6174,15,3,19.5,23.2,26.5
6176,17,5,18.6,23.5,26.8
---
outputFile3
6174,15,3,0,28.3,27
6176,17,5,0,19.7,19.2
---
outputFile4
6174,15,3,0,27,25.4
6176,17,5,0,19.2,18.5
---
```

Comment: You're welcome. Again "Mr Ed" will not get my attention though. Use @EdMorton to contact me and to address me when we're already talking please just use `Ed` and drop the `Mr`.